# Predis using transaction to execute two commands, but one of them failed

Tags: php, redis, predis

## Describe the bug

I use redis list to do a limiter, it works as expected most times, but recently I found that there are some keys without an expiry.Ideally, I "rpush" the value to the list and set expiry as well in one transaction, and I use "watch" as well before the transaction start.

## To Reproduce

I haven't reproduced the bug in my local environment, even I use jmeter to request the related api in batch, for example 1 seconds 500 requests

## Versions:

Predis: v2.1.2
PHP 7.4
Redis Server 5.0.10

## Code sample

```
$redisClient->watch($key);
$current = $redisClient->llen($key);

// Transaction start
$tx = $redisClient->transaction();
if ($current >= $limitNum) {
    $redisClient->unwatch();
    return false;
} else {
  
    if ($redisClient->exists($key)) {
        $tx->rpush($key, $now);

        try {
             $replies = $tx->execute();
             return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Using transaction to let rpush and expire to be an atomic operation
        $tx->rpush($key, $now);
        $tx->expire($key, $expiryTime);

        try {
             $replies = $tx->execute();
             return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

## Others

here is the expected actions in my local redis server

[image]

Redis transaction is atomic. Atomic means either all of the commands or none are processed. So one key should have a expiry in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Redis transactions aren't atomic like that.  They are atomic in the sense that  no other process has access to the keyspace while the transactions in your command execute.  If a command in a transaction fails then subsequent commands will be executed and there isn't a rollback.

Example, let's do a transaction that has a bad command in it:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> exists mylist
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> lpush mylist a b c
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> multi
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> rpop mylist
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd mylist d
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> expire mylist 300
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> exec
1) "a"
2) (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
3) (integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl mylist
(integer) 297
```

Here we check if a list exists, and add some initial items to it.  Then, in a transaction, we pop an item from the list, erroneously try to add a new item thinking the key `mylist` holds a set, then set the time to live on the key `mylist`.  The first and third commands succeed and at the end, `mylist` has a time to live set.  The second command fails.  There is no rollback built into Redis for this - your application would need to use optimistic locking with the `watch` command... this is to detect other processes changing keys your transaction wants to change, before your transaction gets exclusive access to the server.  It isn't a rollback mechanism.

Details: https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/

Comment: cool, thanks for your answer which helps me a lot, and btw, from the documentation  , it seems redis do not support something like  database ACID